# Qt - Include DLLs and compressing files

Tags: c++, qt, dll, size

I'm using Qt creator and I've made an Notepad.
For the installation, almost 10 files are needed for running, the dll's... But they occupy 102 mB! I need to make it at least 40 mB. How can I make it? The DLL's are:

1. Qt5Widgetsd.dll
2. Qt5Cored.dll
3. Qt5Guid.dll
4. libwinpthread-1.dll
5. libstdc++-6.dll
6. libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
7. icuuc51.dll
8. icuin51.dll
9. icudt51.dll

Comment: First you should consider creating a release build of your app, those DLLs are for debug builds of Qt, and will occupy more space. Secondly use UPX to compress the DLLs. You can also try static linking QT with LTO turned on, and then use upx to further reduce size.

Answer (score 0):

Using [UPX compressor](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) might be one way to do it. Also I think you are trying to distribute debug binaries (judging by 'd' suffix on your Qt dlls) which are usually much bigger then release versions.

Comment: Oh god, I didn't remembered that. If I use UPX and just the release, I will be so much light. Thanks, post Solved.

Comment: You can compress .dll files as well as .exe files using UPX, it's a simple command line tool, basic usage is `upx.exe <name of the dll/exe file>`. They will be compressed 'in-place' - you won't have to extract them manually, they will do so automatically at run time.

Comment: Oh, and one more question: can I put the dlls in the exe?

Comment: @LucasHenrique It is possible to do in a few ways, there are tools that embed dll into exe or you can link libraries statically, plus couple less practical ways. There are however issues with all of them, both licensing (in case of 3rd party libraries like Qt) and technical. I wouldn't recommend going into it unless you are really sure what you are doing or you really really need to it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

UPX on Qt dll's are not as good as 7zip. Use UPX with 7z will make things worse.

Qt5.14.2 Core,Gui,Widgets,libwinpthread-1,libstdc++-6,libgcc_s_seh-1,qwindows,qwindowsvistastype

Original: 30MB
UPX: ~20MB
UPX+7z: ~9MB
7z: ~8MB (BEST)